# Glassfish 3.1.2 JDBC performance

Tags: jdbc, glassfish-3, connection-pooling, performance-testing, heap-size

I have a Ubuntu box running on 8 GB of RAM. The Specs are 
Jave : java version 1.6.0_34 
Glassfish Version = GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
Max heap size is 1024.

JDBC setting are all set to default values

Initial and Minimum Pool Size: 8  Connections 
Maximum Pool Size: 32 Connections 
Pool Resize Quantity:2 Connections 
Idle Timeout: 300
Seconds Max Wait Time: 60000 Milliseconds

I am expecting at peak **1000** concurrent users to submit a form. On the lower side at least 300 concurrent users. 
My typical database operation uses PreparedStatement and Resultset and they are closed in Finally block along with the Connection. The project uses JSP, Servlet and Pojo. I have yet to venture into EJB and JPA.

Question 1 : JDBC connection 
Initial and Minimum Pool Size: 300 Connections
Maximum Pool Size: 1000 Connections
**Pool Resize Quantity: ?**
Idle Timeout: 300 Seconds (Keep it as default?)
Max Wait Time: 60000 Milliseconds (Keep it as default?)

Question 2: Should the code have manual commit? Will this improve the Performance?

Question 3: As the database server SQL 2012 is shared, there are two projects sharing the same JDBC Connection Pool. Should I separate it out to improve as I understand each will run its own thread?

Question 4: How to calculate the size of the Heap? Is this a good practice? 
-server -XX:+AggressiveHeap -Xmx3500m -Xms3500m **-Xss?**
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC

Sorry for making it very long.

I just wish to understand how to scale the server?

Comment: Try to benchmark your app using jMeter. Don't try to optimize without knowing where the bottlenecks are. [1] if it works, yes, keep the defaults [2] not significantly I guess [3] wait for JMeter results, but yes, it may help to have a dedicated DB [4] I'd stay with -Xmx and Xms only. Scale the server clustering GlassFish first.

Comment: I have yet to use jMeter on JDBC.will learn and check. [2] I did not use any manual commit. [3] I configured each application to have its own JNDI pool connection. No Connection Leak spotted. [4] No changes to the original values and the site is going well.

Comment: try http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

Answer (score 0):

The changes I made to the Glassfish Server.

1. Increase max heap size to 2 GB on 8 GB box.
2. No changes to the garbage collector.
3. The Connection Pool setting were doubled to original value. At a point, it maanged 700 concurrent connnection, which means there was no loss of data. Not entirely sure how this was mathematically possible, but it was handled by Database and Glassfish Server.